# Expandable message div based on label width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

In my application I have a little label area that I have popping down to display messages. These messages are of different lengths and I want the label to take up as little space as possible width and height wise.

It seems silly to create an id for all of these labels instead of just reusing the CSS. However, I am having difficulty making my widths dynamically expand/compress based on the label. Is there a good way of doing this? Is there sort of magical mix of min-width and width: auto to be used? Should this be taken care of with jquery on start of each page to make it overwrite the width for that pages label? I've tried a number of methods from google/S.O. and none have produced the result I want so far. Everytime the labels width expanded the parent div.

Here is a look at my current attempt:

HTML:

```
<div id="divStatus">
        <label id ="statusContainer">Loading ...</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#statusContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important;
    z-index: 101;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    overflow: hidden; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;
    color: #8b6d80;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 120px;
}

#divStatus {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 101;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Here are some screenshots with what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: small label]

---

[image: bigger label]

Does anyone know the sleekest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, very similar to @GCyrillus answer, but tweaked a little to get it to hang at the top how I want:

```
#statusContainer {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow:         0 0 5px black;
    color: #8b6d80;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 120px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 101;
}

#divStatus {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set label in `absolute` `position` since parent is already so.

`Display:table;` + `margin:auto;` will do fine for your `label`. Using table-layout, `label` will be like a box but will be expanding/shrinking according to its content: [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qHezE).

You may use class to easily reuse them :
Example:

```
.divStatus {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.statusMsg {
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  color:gray;
  border:solid 1px;
  border-radius:0.15em;
  background:lightgray;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="divStatus">
        <label class ="statusMsg">Loading ...</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you might even quit absolute positionning if you tried it only to size your boxe.